# Compilation is not supported for following modules: flutter_project. Unfortunately can't have non-Gradle Java modules and Android-Gradle modules

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I opened the **Flutter project** in **Android Studio**, manually imported the *Android Gradle Module* within it, and it is working well except for the error below:

```
Unsupported Modules Detected:

Compilation is not supported for the following modules: flutter_...

Unfortunately, you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and Android-Gradle modules in one project.
```

[image]

I wanted to resolve this error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: which type of code you want?

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code or error messages, paste them into your post as text, surrounded by ```. This helps keeping StackOverflow searchable and accessible.